# Get image resolution from image file

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing

I'm trying use this code to get image resolution from file

```
bool GetImageSizeEx(const char *fn, int *x,int *y)
{ 
    FILE *f=fopen(fn,"rb"); 

    if (f==0) return false;

    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END); 
    long len=ftell(f); 
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET); 

    if (len<24) {
        fclose(f); 
        return false;
    }

  // Strategy:
  // reading GIF dimensions requires the first 10 bytes of the file
  // reading PNG dimensions requires the first 24 bytes of the file
  // reading JPEG dimensions requires scanning through jpeg chunks
  // In all formats, the file is at least 24 bytes big, so we'll read that always
    unsigned char buf[24]; fread(buf,1,24,f);


  // For JPEGs, we need to read the first 12 bytes of each chunk.
  // We'll read those 12 bytes at buf+2...buf+14, i.e. overwriting the existing buf.
    if (buf[0]==0xFF && buf[1]==0xD8 && buf[2]==0xFF && buf[3]==0xE0 && buf[6]=='J' && buf[7]=='F' && buf[8]=='I' && buf[9]=='F')
    {
        long pos=2;
        while (buf[2]==0xFF)
        {
            if (buf[3]==0xC0 || buf[3]==0xC1 || buf[3]==0xC2 || buf[3]==0xC3 || buf[3]==0xC9 || buf[3]==0xCA || buf[3]==0xCB) 
                break;

            pos += 2+(buf[4]<<8)+buf[5];
            if (pos+12>len) break;
            fseek(f,pos,SEEK_SET); 
            fread(buf+2,1,12,f);   
        }
    }


    fclose(f);

  // JPEG: (first two bytes of buf are first two bytes of the jpeg file; rest of buf is the DCT frame
    if (buf[0]==0xFF && buf[1]==0xD8 && buf[2]==0xFF)
    {     
        *y = (buf[7]<<8) + buf[8]; 
        *x = (buf[9]<<8) + buf[10]; 

        return true;
    }

  // GIF: first three bytes say "GIF", next three give version number. Then dimensions
    if (buf[0]=='G' && buf[1]=='I' && buf[2]=='F')
    { 
        *x = buf[6] + (buf[7]<<8);
        *y = buf[8] + (buf[9]<<8);
        return true;
    }

  // PNG: the first frame is by definition an IHDR frame, which gives dimensions
    if ( buf[0]==0x89 && buf[1]=='P' && buf[2]=='N' && buf[3]=='G' && buf[4]==0x0D && buf[5]==0x0A && buf[6]==0x1A && buf[7]==0x0A && buf[12]=='I' && buf[13]=='H' && buf[14]=='D' && buf[15]=='R')
    {
        *x = (buf[16]<<24) + (buf[17]<<16) + (buf[18]<<8) + (buf[19]<<0);
        *y = (buf[20]<<24) + (buf[21]<<16) + (buf[22]<<8) + (buf[23]<<0);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**return always x == 26112 and y == 30825** for all images any type and any resolution

I compiled with VS 2010 SP1 on Win7 x64

**Update**

I'm trying to open jpg files which was created by Photoshop. Photoshop encode JPEG Files with Exif Metadata

Debugger show (right click to fullsize)

[image]

so code look now:

```
if ((buf[0]==0xFF && buf[1]==0xD8 && buf[2]==0xFF && buf[3]==0xE0 && buf[6]=='J' && buf[7]=='F' && buf[8]=='I' && buf[9]=='F') ||
        (buf[0]==0xFF && buf[1]==0xD8 && buf[2]==0xFF && buf[3]==0xE1 && buf[6]=='E' && buf[7]=='x' && buf[8]=='i' && buf[9]=='f'))
    {
        long pos=2;
        while (buf[2]==0xFF)
        {
            if (buf[3]==0xC0 || buf[3]==0xC1 || buf[3]==0xC2 || buf[3]==0xC3 || buf[3]==0xC9 || buf[3]==0xCA || buf[3]==0xCB) 
                break;

            pos += 2+(buf[4]<<8)+buf[5];
            if (pos+12>len) break;
            fseek(f,pos,SEEK_SET); 
            fread(buf+2,1,12,f);   
        }
    }
```

Comment: You tagged this as C++. At least use things like `string` and `fstream` that aren't C.

Comment: Consider using the GIL: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html

Comment: While this is C-style code, there's nothing wrong with it being tagged C++ as she/he may accept solutions (e.g. the one larsmans linked) that are suited for a C++ environment, despite how the tiny snippet of fairly code displayed here is written. Additionally, there's not much context to judge her/his coding style on, and not much reason for it.

Comment: @Kaganar: The problem is that the solution will likely be very different.  C and C++ are emphatically *not* the same language.

Comment: Ahh, nice find! There you go. Debugger to your rescue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code for all three formats and **it works perfectly fine** for various resolutions! Only thing I would suggest is call your `GetImageSizeEx` appropriately (Escaping the backslash)

Something like

```
int x,y;

GetImageSizeEx("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\pavan2.png", &x, &y);
printf("%d %d", x, y );
```

A few possible cases for the failure your noticing might be that the `fopen` itself is failing because of some wrong filename etc and `x` and `y` are never modified inside `GetImageSizeEx`. Or another case wherein you read a wrong file and you are not able to read the appropriate headers and hence again, `x` and `y` are not modified at all! And may be you never initialized `x` and `y` in your calling function and hence some garbage is being shown?

**PS**: I compiled it with `gcc 4.6.1` mingw on Windows 7

Comment: I have the same execute code. I try init x and y before add to func, 2) check x,y vals in GetImageSizeEx body, 3) check fopen and file path and etc. result always  x == 26112 and y == 30825. PS I compiled with VS 2010 SP1 on Win7 x64

Comment: @mola10 Debugger is your last resort. And if really gcc and VS are behaving differently, then we have something to learn here